# PDO $_GET the id of a task to delete a specific task in the database when the user click the delete button of that task

Tags: php, html, pdo

I have a problem to get the id of a task in order to delete that task when the user clicks on the delete button of that task in the UI. I have two tables, one is the "To-do Task" table, and the other is the "Completed Task" table. In the code, I did ask the user what task in what table they want to delete via form by using the task's id and the table name. Now I do not want to use the form, but I want to have a delete button next to each task in each table so that the user just needs to click on that button to delete the task. Can you teach me how to do it? Thank you

```
    <?php
session_start();
require 'connect.php';
 $owner = $_SESSION['name'];
//delete data in the table the user want based on id of the data
    if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
        $section = $_POST['delete_com_in'];
        $task_id=$_POST['delete_com_in_id'];
        $deleteQuery="DELETE FROM $section WHERE id=:task_id";
        $preparedDeleteStatement = $conn->prepare($deleteQuery);
        $preparedDeleteStatement->bindValue(':task_id',$task_id);
        $valueDelete=$preparedDeleteStatement->execute();
    }

//fetch data into table (incomplete and complete)
$displayQuery="SELECT * FROM incomplete where owner=:owner";
$displayTask= $conn->prepare($displayQuery);
$displayTask->bindValue(':owner', $owner);
$displayTask->execute();
$allTask=$displayTask->fetchAll();

echo "<table  class=\"incomplete_table\"><caption>To-do Tasks</caption><tr><th>ID</th><th>Title</th><th>Description</th><th>Due Date</th><th>Time</th></tr>";
if(count($allTask) > 0)
{
    foreach ($allTask as $row) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["title"]."</td><td>".$row["description"]."</td><td>".$row["due_date"]."</td><td>".$row["time"]."</td></tr>";
    }
}

$displayQueryComplete="SELECT * FROM complete where owner=:owner";
$displayTaskComplete= $conn->prepare($displayQueryComplete);
$displayTaskComplete->bindValue(':owner', $owner);
$displayTaskComplete->execute();
$allTaskComplete= $displayTaskComplete->fetchAll();

echo "<table  class=\"complete_table\"><caption>Completed Tasks</caption><tr><th>ID</th><th>Title</th><th>Description</th><th>Due Date</th><th>Time</th></tr>";
if(count($allTaskComplete) > 0)
{
    foreach ($allTaskComplete as $row) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["title"]."</td><td>".$row["description"]."</td><td>".$row["due_date"]."</td><td>".$row["time"]."</td></tr>";
    }


   }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main_list.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="./add_task.js" defer></script>
        <title>Main List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container">
        <button id="buttonMainList"><a href="./logout.php">Logout</a></button>
            <p id="userNameHere"><?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?></p>
        </div>
        <h1 id="inform">TO-DO LIST</h1>
        <div id="menu">
          <label for="action">Choose an action:</label>
            <select id="action" name="action" onchange='onSelectChangeHandler()'>
                <option value="delete">Delete</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    <!--delete form-->
    <div id="delete">
    <div id="delete_task_form">
                <p id="delete_task">Delete Task</p>
                <form id="delete_form" name="delete_form" method="post">
                    <div id="delete_section">
                        <input type="radio" id="delete_com_complete" name="delete_com_in" value="complete">
                        <label for="delete_com_complete">Completed</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="delete_com_incomplete" name="delete_com_in" value="incomplete">
                        <label for="delete_com_incomplete">Incomplete</label>
                    </div>
                    <div id="delete_section_id">
                        <label for="delete_com_in_id">What ID?</label>
                        <input type="text" id="delete_com_in_id" name="delete_com_in_id"><br>
                    </div>
                        
                        <input id="submit_delete_form" type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">
                </form>
                <br>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: _“I have two tables, one is the "To-do Task" table, and the other is the "Completed Task" table.”_ - are there significant structural differences between the data you store in each table? If not, then those should rather be _one_ table to begin with (with an additional column, that marks a task as either “to do” or “completed”.)

Comment: Don't  you realize that you made your code WIDE OPEN to SQL injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's not a correct way of work but without a form you can use the  tag to pass throught get the id of the task to delete:

```
<html>
      <a href="example.com?task=98">Delete button</a>
</html>
```

Also, you need to known the table that the user want delete so you need to create two buttons each one will represent one table:

```
<html>
      <a href="example.com?task=98&table=To-do Task">Delete button table 1</a>
      <a href="example.com?task=98&table=Completed Task">Delete button table 2</a>
</html>
```

98 is an exemple of a id. When you have passed the id of the task you only have to receive it by $_GET:

```
<?php 
   if(isset($_GET["task"])){
       $Task=$_GET["task"];
   }
?>
```

Once you have the id you have to do the same with the table:

```
<?php 
   if(isset($_GET["table"])){
          if($_GET["table"]=="To-do Task"){
               $Table="To-do Task";
          }else{
               $Table="Completed Task";
          }    
   }
?>
```

Finally you only have to delete the task depending the table:

```
<?php 
     if($Table=="To-do Task"){
           $deletetask= $con->prepare("DELETE FROM `To-do` Task WHERE ID=?;");
           $deletetask->execute([$Task]);
      }else{
           $deletetask= $con->prepare("DELETE FROM Completed Task WHERE ID=?;");
           $deletetask->execute([$Task]);
      }
?>
```

Remember always sanitize and validate inputs from the users or values than can be manipulated by the user

Comment: Thank you for your help but how do we know what table the user wants to delete the task on?

Comment: Your welcome, I have edited the answer and now you can see how to make it with two tables. Modify the name of the tables and what you need for make it work. The important is that you see and understand how it works. Remember that you can vote this answer if it helped you. Have a nice day.

Comment: The task in <a href="example.com?task=98&table=To-do Task">Delete button table 1</a>, <a href="example.com?task=98&table=Completed Task">Delete button table 2</a> is the name of the column inside the database or I can use whatever name I want?

Comment: whatever you want,  which is between <a>here</a> it's what will appear in the button text, which it's in name=example.com?nameofvalue=value. ? it's required you can change the rest. nameofvalue will be the name of the $_GET var and value will be the value of this var.

Comment: Then the  if(isset($_GET["task"])){...}, if(isset($_GET["table"])){...}, if($Table=="To-do Task"){...) else{...}, can I put them in the same delete.php file? I want to generate the **delete button for each task** in the tables

Comment: Yes, the isset only checks if exists $_GET[nameofthevalue]. each button should has one id, for example: one will be example.com?task=99, then the next button will be example.com?task=100, the 99 or 100 will be the id that you will run in the delete query for identify the task.